# How to nest image inside chioce sets or action buttons using adaptive cards for Outlook actionable messages

Tags: power-automate, adaptive-cards, actionable-notification

I am working on a requirement to implement the Outlook Actionable Message through adoptive Cards. I am now building the JSON here : https://amdesigner.azurewebsites.net/.
I actually want to display images in place of choice set options. SO that it will display images in place of options available inside choice set.

Another requirement is to have a background image for the Submit Action button. So, this is a declarative JSON notations, can we some how nest controls inside another. Meaning here want to nest image inside button or choice set.